# how to check if the expression are valid while performing filter in a DataFrame

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, filter, apache-spark-sql

consider any big filtering expression like below,

`filter_expression` = `(((col1 ='val1') AND(col2 ='val2') ) OR ((col3 ='val3') AND(col4 in ('val4','val5')) AND(col5 in ('val6','val7')) ) ..................................)`

If I have a DF with many no of columns and if I need to filter how to ensure that the expression is valid ?

`df.filter(filter_expression)`

I would like to know the

> 1.how to check long filter expressions are valid  ?
>
> 2.Is this proper way of filtering large expressions the DataFrame in spark ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Dataset API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes) to have `compile-time` checking

Create a `case class Columns` consisting of `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, etc, and convert the `DataFrame` to a `Dataset[Columns]` using `val dataset = dataFrame.as[Columns]`

And then you can filter

```
dataset.filter(columns => columns.col1.equals("val1") && (columns.col2.equals("val2") || columns.col3.equals("val3")))
```

and so on.